# GetViewForAnnotation is never called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I am creating a MapView where I want to display some custom Annotations.

So I think usually what you do is add some `IMKAnnotation` to the `MKMapView` using the `AddAnnotation` method. I make sure to invoke that on the main thread like:

```cs
new NSObject().InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    _mapView.AddAnnotation(myNewAnnotation);
});
```

After these I are added I do see that the `MKMapView` now contains all the annotations I added in the `Annotations` property when inspecting with the debugger.

However, the problem is that `GetViewForAnnotation` is never invoked, no matter how I do it.

I've tried:

```cs
_mapView.GetViewForAnnotation += ViewForAnnotation;

private MKAnnotationView ViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

I've tried implementing my own delegate:

```cs
public class MyMapViewDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

_delegate = new MyMapViewDelegate();
_mapView.Delegate = _delegate;
```

I've tried using `WeakDelegate`:

```cs
public class MapView : ViewController, IMKMapViewDelegate
{
    private MKMapView _mapView;

    public override void ViewDidLoad() {
        _mapView = new MKMapView();
        _mapView.WeakDelegate = this;
    }

    [Export("mapView:viewForAnnotation:")]
    public MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to trigger the `GetViewForAnnotation` method. Any ideas what I do wrong?

**EDIT:**

A bit more details what I have now.

```cs
[Register("MapView")]
public class MapView : MvxViewController<MapViewModel>
{
    private MKMapView _mapView;
    private NMTAnnotationManager _annotationManager;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        _mapView = new MKMapView();
        _mapView.GetViewForAnnotation += GetViewForAnnotation;
        _annotationManager = new NMTAnnotationManager(_mapView);

        var bindSet = this.CreateBindingSet<MapView, MapViewModel>();
        bindSet.Bind(_annotationManager).For(a => a.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Locations).OneWay();
        bindSet.Apply();

        Add(_mapView);

        View.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();

        View.AddConstraints(
            _mapView.AtTopOf(View),
            _mapView.AtLeftOf(View),
            _mapView.AtRightOf(View),
            _mapView.AtBottomOf(View));
    }

    private MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapview, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `NMTAnnotationManager` simply weak subscribes to the `INotifyCollectionChanged` event the `ObservableCollection` which is used as `ItemsSource` in the binding. When the collection changes it simply adds and removes the Annotations from the `MKMapView`, nothing magical happens here. I have verified that it does indeed add, in this case 13, different `IMKAnnotation` instances to the `MKMapView` and they can be inspected in the `Annotations` property of it.

So as @Philip suggested in his answer, `GetViewForAnnotation` does get set before Annotations are added to the MapView. But if I put a breakpoint or some trace in the method it never gets hit.

The same code above, just with a simple `MKMapViewDelegate` like so:

```cs
public class MyMapViewDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public override void MapLoaded(MKMapView mapView)
    {
        Mvx.Trace("MapLoaded");
    }

    public override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        Mvx.Trace("GetViewForAnnotation");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Does not work either. Although, the `MapLoaded` event gets hit for each time the map is rendered, but why does `GetViewForAnnotation` not get hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so apparently the problem was PEBKAC.

The annotation indeed got added to the `MKMapView`. However, none of them had their `Coordinate` property set. So obviously the map did not know where to present them and never called `GetViewForAnnotation`.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'm doing it is:

- Storyboard with a ViewController which contains a MKMapView
- MKMapView Delegate to the ViewController is set in IB in the Connections Inspector

In `ViewDidLoad` I make sure I set this first: 
`mapView.GetViewForAnnotation += GetViewForAnnotation;`

I had problems with it never beeing called too, and I fixed it with making sure that I set the event for GetViewForAnnotation before I added some annotations.

Comment: I do make sure that `GetViewForAnnotation` is set before I add Annotations, so it is not the problem it seems.

Comment: @Philip do you have git repo?. i have the same problem